# Use append for dynamically form, call javascript function from tag div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Can you call javascript function from another javascript function?

When I call from Tag Html this javascript chzn work correctly.

But if I call from another function javascript, thats not work.
`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.chzn').chosen( { width: '100%' }); //method chzn that I want call

    var max_fields      = 5;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");
    var div = "<div><select class='chzn' name='nama_obat[]'><?php foreach($listobat ->result() as $row):?><option><?php echo $row->nama_obat ?></option><?php endforeach;?></select><a class='col-lg-3' href='#' id='delete'>Delete</a></div>";
    var x = 1;

    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(div); //add input box
        }
        else
        {
          alert('You Reached the limits')
      }
  });

    $(wrapper).on("click","#delete", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

});
</script>
```

`

Thanks for your help

Comment: `gridViewAndroid = new View(mContext);` This creates an object and the next line immediately throws it away.

Comment: you need to learn how view recycling works.

Answer (score 1):

If `convertView` was not null (it was recycled), you were not setting any value and you just returned the same view with same image. GridView is recycling views. If you set height to 100, all 7 views were inflated. If you set hight to 200, only 6 were inflated and when you scrolled down, the first two were recycled and you have to set them values that corespond to their new position.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View gridViewAndroid;

    if (convertView == null) {
       gridViewAndroid = new View(mContext);
       gridViewAndroid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);
    } else {
       gridViewAndroid = (View) convertView;
    }

    TextView textViewAndroid = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
    ImageView imageViewAndroid = (ImageView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_image);

    textViewAndroid.setText(mTopic.get(position));
    imageViewAndroid.setImageBitmap(mImage.get(position));

    return gridViewAndroid;
}
```

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: If `convertView` was not null (it was recycled), you were not setting any value and you just returned the same view with same image. GridView is recycling views. If you set height to 100, all 7 views were inflated. If you set hight to 200, only 6 were inflated and when you scrolled down, the first two were recycled and you have to set them values that corespond to their no position.

Comment: @user1779222 ohhhhhhhhh, yaaaaaa I understand. Thanks all.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice simple but crazy. sorry i am newbe